# How to make collapsing and sticky view above recycler view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am new in Android development. I need to make something like this: [Reference](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18jy63y5E5Ro5LShJ-yd_UcsQHeYRfxI6/view?usp=sharing)

As you can see at the top, there is an orange view with the text 'Likes'. when I scroll the vertical recycler view, that orange view will disappear, and it will be changed with a white sticky header in the top of recycler view.

How to do that? I am new in Android, and unfortunately, my company asks me to make something like that.

What element, layout, or technique that I need to learn first to make something like that ?

Comment: Research CollapsibleToolbar and you'll find samples and then customize it to look like this exactly

Comment: Use `CoordinatorLayout` with `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.  You may search in GitHub or google or youtube. Github and Youtube can be your best choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ScrollingActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="top"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/coffee_1200"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:text="Like LuaPass?\nBuy me a coffee :)"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```